# Trying to replace last 2 octets of ip address

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following ip address "192.168.2.65"

Is there a way to convert the last 2 octets to 0.

I found the following, but it only lets me replace the last one, i need to replace the last 2.

```
ip = 192.168.2.65
output='.'.join(ip.split('.')[:-1]+["0"])
print(output)
```

which gives me 192.168.2.0 and i would like to be 192.168.0.0

Comment: Is this due to subnetting? Are you trying to find the network address for the subnet presented? What is the logic for changing it to `0.0`?

Answer (score 4):

Index `-1` means the last index. If you want to change two, change your index to `-2`.

```py
output='.'.join(ip.split('.')[:-2]+["0", "0"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regex based approach here:

```py
ip = "192.168.2.65"
output = re.sub(r'\.\d+\.\d+$', '.0.0', ip)
print(output)   # prints 192.168.0.0
```

Comment: Or you can just sub the `'.0.0'` as the replacement: `re.sub(r'\.\d+\.\d+$', '.0.0', ip)`. Also, don't forget to `import re`.

Answer (score 0):

Dependant on the logic you are trying to apply.. if you are simply wanting to modify a string, the other answers are correct.

However, if you are looking to get the network address for the subnet an address resides in, you should handle the addresses correctly and use the `ipaddress` module.

This will assist in calculating the correct network & broadcast addresses, and allow you to check inclusions in networks etc.

---

```
import ipaddress

interface = IPv4Interface('192.168.2.35/255.255.0.0')

print(interface.network)

#192.168.0.0/16

print(interface.network.network_address)

#192.168.0.0

print(interface.network.broadcast_address)

#192.168.255.255
```